# Java keystore - Imported certificate chain is untrusted

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, keystore, x509

I'm trying to add https capability to an Spring Boot app.

I purchased a certificate from Comodo but am having a lot of difficulty getting it to be trusted.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107096/springboot-and-comodo-https-configuration-for-the-web-application) and imported the certificate chain as follows

```
// The first was arleady trusted under a different alias, added anyway

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias AAACertificateServices -file AAACertificateServices.crt -keystore domain.keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias USERTrustRSAAAACA -file  USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt -keystore domain.keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA -file  SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -keystore domain.keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file mydoman.crt -keystore domain.keystore
```

However, when I verify the certificates in Keystore Explorer, the verification fails, and the certificate chain is not linked.

Any ideas how I can solve this aggravating problem?

Comment: I think there may be two different problems. Did you do the `-import[cert]`s, particularly the last one, to the same keystore _and entry/alias_ as you used for `-genkey[pair]`? If not, that would explain the certs not being linked (as a chain) in the keystore, and the keystore not being usable for an SSL/TLS server. However, the KSE Verify operation just seems to be broken, at least in the version I have (5.5.1) -- not onlyl does it say valid Sectigo CA certs '[don't] chain to an anchor' it also does this for certs in cacerts which are by definition anchors.

Comment: Interesting. I created the certificate request using commodo's online certificate request creation page. So I don't believe I used "genkey" at all. Regarding your second suggestion, I will test on the public website.

Comment: Thank you! The part about the same alias for the genkey did the trick.